# How can I trigger a javascript that adjusts the size of DIVs to work as quickly as possible?

Tags: javascript

I am going to be using the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.document.onload = function(e){
        var aheight = document.getElementById("a").offsetHeight;
        var bheight = document.getElementById("b").offsetHeight;
        if(aheight > bheight) {
            document.getElementById("b").offsetHeight = aheight;
        }else {
            document.getElementById("a").offsetHeight = bheight;
         }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="a" class="grid_6" style="background-color: #ff00ff">
        <div class="block-border">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="b" class="grid_6" style="background-color: #ffff00">
        <div class="block-border">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.grid_6 {
    width: 200px;
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.99%;
    margin-right: 0.99%;
}
```

I'll use this to equalize the height between two DIVs on my page. Can someone tell me where is the best place to put this script so that it works as quickly as possible. Also is the window.document.onload the best trigger for this? Could I alternatively trigger on the DIVs with element id "a" and "b" being loaded? I just want to avoid a user seeing the DIVS change is size.

Comment: Do you have external resources which can make a and b change size ?

Comment: Put it in a script tag immediately after `#a` and `#b` have finished loading.

Comment: I suggest `display: table-cell` and `display:table-row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While tables within tables within tables with empty cells for padding are bad, the use of the table-related CSS is perfectly fine. Consider this CSS-only solution:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="grid_6">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
    <div class="grid_6">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
  display: table-row
}

.grid_6{
  display: table-cell
  width: 50%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NqXgd/

Note that there does not have to be an element with `display: table`; the browser will insert an anonymous element automatically. You can also write `#parent{display:table}`, and have an anonymous `table-row` inserted around the cell-styled `div`s.

Note that if you don't set explicit widths, the browser is free to choose them (say, to equalise the heights). This might be beneficial, or you may set some widths explicitly to constrain the layout.

Comment: There's a downside : now the divs are side by side instead of one under the other...

Comment: @dystroy I thought they were supposed to be side by side?

Comment: Nothing in the question seems to suggest it. If you try OP's code, you 'll see the divs one under the othr.

Comment: They are side-by-side in OP's case (except on very narrow screens), if I read the CSS correctly. Also, it'unlikely one would like to equalize heights on divs that are not side by side.

Comment: Hum... you might be right... I hadn't paid attention to the CSS as I tested in the thin column of jsbin...^^... +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the size of `a` and `b` aren't dependent of external resources, then you don't have to wait for the `load` event, you can simply put this at the end of the body (or anywhere after the definition of any element which can impact the size of `a` and `b`) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var aheight = document.getElementById("a").offsetHeight;
var bheight = document.getElementById("b").offsetHeight;
if(aheight > bheight) {
    document.getElementById("b").style.height = aheight+'px';
}else {
    document.getElementById("a").style.height = bheight+'px';
 }
</script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ubusid/5/edit)

Note that I changed `offsetHeight =` to `style.height =` as you can't change the `offsetHeight` of an element.

Answer (score 0):

The offset sizes are read-only, to change a height in script you need to set the element's **style.height** to the offset number +'px'.